# Is converting a C++ method to a C function with a pointer argument an acceptable pattern?

Tags: c++, c, functions

I use C++ on ESP-32. When registering a timer I have to do this:

```
timer_args.callback = reinterpret_cast<esp_timer_cb_t>(&SoundMixer::soundCallback);
timer_args.arg = this;
```

Here the timer calls `soundCallback`.

And the same thing when registering a task:

```
xTaskCreate(reinterpret_cast<TaskFunction_t>(&SoundProviderTask::taskProviderCode), "SProvTask", stackSize, this, 10, &taskHandle);
```

So the method is started in a separated task.

GCC always warns me about these conversions, but it works just as planned.

Is it acceptable in production code? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A `reinterpret_cast` is always fishy unless you know *exactly* what you are doing. Here, your code happens to work only due to GCC's calling convention for C++ methods, but this smells heavily like undefined behaviour. In particular you should not assume that member functions are in any way compatible with normal function pointers.

The usual approach would be to instead define a C-compatible function with the appropriate signature, which internally calls the C++ method. For example:

```
extern "C" static void my_timer_callback(void* arg) {
  static_cast<SoundMixer*>(arg)->soundCallback();
}
```

This cast is fine because we are casting back from a `void*` to the type of the pointed-to object.

Details:

- `extern "C"` specifies the [*language linkage*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) of this function. Language linkage affects name mangling and the [*calling convention*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) of the function. Member functions cannot have C language linkage. Language linkage is largely orthogonal to internal/external linkage.
- For a callback the function may be “private”, i.e. have internal linkage. The C code never refers to the callback by name. The above code snippet specifies internal linkage through the `static` keyword (not a static method!). Alternatively, the function could have been placed into an anonymous namespace.

  I am not entirely sure about the interactions between `extern "C"` and `static` (internal linkage). E.g. `[dcl.link]` says that “All function types, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage have a language linkage.” I interpret this so that the *type* of `my_timer_callback` has C language linkage, but that its function *name* does not.
- A `static_cast` is appropriate here because we know the real type of the `arg` but cannot express it within the type system. In contrast a `reinterpret_cast` is appropriate when we want to reinterpret a bit pattern, e.g. a pointer to a numeric type.
- Functions are not ordinary objects, and member functions even less so. You may reinterpret-cast between function pointer types as long as the function is only invoked through its real type (and analogously for member function pointers). Whether you can cast function pointers to other types (e.g. object pointers or void pointers) is implementation-defined ([background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358843/why-are-function-pointers-and-data-pointers-incompatible-in-c-c)). On POSIX casts between function pointers and `void*` are allowed so that `dlsym()` can work. Other casts involving (member) function pointers are undefined. In particular, casts between member functions and function pointers are not possible.

Comment: Doesn't `std::bind` also assume object pointer as first method argument?

Comment: @val Yes, but that doesn't mean that member functions are compatible with ordinary functions, merely that bind() uses the [INVOKE algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) which handles member functions as a separate case from ordinary function objects incl. function pointers. Because std::bind() creates a functor it is not suitable for interfacing with C.

Comment: Another question: why do I need `extern "C"` here? Is C linkage important in this case?

Comment: @val If you want to be able to call that function from C, it must use the C calling convention. This can be done by declaring that function with C language linkage, or by compiler-specific extensions (like `__attribute__((cdecl))`, but please don't do that). A C++ function is not guaranteed to have a C-compatible calling convention otherwise (though in GCC it typically works out fine).

Comment: @val For the details on why `extern "C"` is formally necessary, see `[dcl.link]` "Two function types with diﬀerent language linkages are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical." and `[expr.call]` "Calling a function through an expression whose function type is diﬀerent from the function type of the
called function’s deﬁnition results in undeﬁned behavior"

Comment: @amon This approach advocated by amon maybe technically correct, but the existing approach of using static C++ functions is VERY widely used and VERY safe (in almost all cases - maybe all). And this approach DOES have the issue that it eliminates the possabilyt of using C++ features to hide names. Making the name an EXTERNAL name, exported from your module is a NEGATIVE, and a POINTLESS negative. Perhaps there no way around it. But I would use a private static C++ function instead.

Comment: @LewisPringle It seems your points have already been addressed far better than I could have (and thank you for checking my answer – I'm not actually very experienced with C++ so I appreciate additional info). As an additional point I'd just like to add that I am specifically suggesting a `static` function here to avoid namespace pollution, though I didn't explicitly mention it in the answer.

Comment: @amon I still don't like the solution because it requires use of a deprecated way of doing that hiding (static) and awkward syntax (for similar purposes in c++ u use anonymous  namespace or private static methods). But the in-principle unsafely of what the questioner suggested and I've always done was made clear to me, so what u advocate appears the best compromise.

Comment: @LewisPringle : An in-class `static` function with `extern "C"` is by all means fine. The code posted by OP assumes that `SoundMixer::soundCallback` is a normal member function. Personally, I also wouldn't mind having a separate `extern "C"` function defined in an anonymous namespace, which calls through to the object passed in as the callback's argument - but then you run into visibility issues and all that.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395192/why-does-c11-not-support-declaring-extern-c-on-a-static-member-function  says you cannot do this. I would be FAR happier if this was true. I tried to add  extern "C" static  void f (); to a class, and it fails with visual studio.net 2017.

Comment: @LewisPringle : My bad. I guess we're stuck with free functions in an anonymous namespace, then.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar You know `extern "C"`-symbols have very limited tolerance for C++ namespaces?

Comment: Also note that since captureless lambdas bind to C function pointers, the amount of necessary boilerplate code on the C++ side can be reduced quite drastically.

Comment: @ComicSansMS But I don't think you can declare a specific language linkage for lambdas?

Comment: @amon True, but this is also not necessary in this case. If the API accepts a C function pointer, a captureless lambda is guaranteed to work here without additional qualifiers. In particular, there is no need for `extern "C"`, as the lambda is never referred to by name (so no mangling issues), but only through the pointer.

Comment: @ComicSansMS What `extern "C"` specifically does is implementation-dependent, but will typically select an appropriate ABI/*calling convention*, in addition to preventing name mangling. A function pointer and an extern-C function pointer are _different types_ (see [Ben Voigt's comment above](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/376746#comment828335_376749)). In practice GCC does not go out of its way to make your life miserable, but what you are advocating is technically UB.

Comment: @ComicSansMS It might work, but that's non-conforming: [It only converts to function-pointer with C++ language-linkage per standard.](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-7)

Answer (score -1):

Personally, the most compatible, easy to implement and easy to understand approach that I've found is to just provide a "wrapper" function, compatible with the expected C interface, which internally calls the method (and, in case it's not static, instantiate or use an existing instance to do that). It could be seen as a sort of a variation of the Adapter Design Pattern.

Comment: Isn't that what amon answered?

Comment: @Dronz after a second read, yes, it's mostly that. As soon as I read `static` I saw it as a method and for some reason didn't realize it doesn't pass the `this` pointer as the first argument (and the following debate on the use of `std::bind` reinforced it). But yes, you're absolutely right! (Sorry for the double answer!)

Comment: Yeah, `static` has at least three different, distinct meanings. And you'll mix them up if you are not careful. I would say, it's really helpful to understand the distinctions between the different uses of `static`, as each is a great tool in its own right.